# No USB Keyboard or Mouse, Power Cuts off, Missing "Mouse and pointer" in Device Manager after Win10 Update

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

My Windows 10 PC recently updated and my USB mouse and keyboard no longer work. In fact any Human Interface Device (HID) won't work and shows up as a `Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)` in the Device Manager HID's properties.

I know it was the Windows 10 update that caused it as I had a Restore Point I was able to revert back to a working PC state, before the 90 day restore point limit deleted it.

My USB Ports are working as my External HDD is recognised. However, when I plug in a Dell USB mouse the lights / power cut off right at the Windows initial login screen..

I did everything, starting with a PS/2 Keyboard:

- Update Drivers - failed
- Uninstall Drivers - they re-install and fail
- In Device Mgr > USB Hub > Power Mgmt > Turn off the "allowed to power manage" - failed
- In Power Options "disabled the USB turn off power"  - failed
- The registry LowerFilter and UpperFilter hacks - to no avail.
- Disabled "Fast Startup" - no luck
- Obviously tested Mouse & Keyboard on another PC - works

My PCs USB ports do detect my mouse keyboard when I plug them in, I hear the chime, however the power lights go off on the mouse a few seconds later. Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days troubleshooting and finding lots of poor people who didn't take a Restore Point before trying the RegKey hacks, I finally found a solution.

> I ended up calling Microsoft support who went through many troubleshooting efforts with me.  In the end, I needed to perform a full Windows upgrade to correct the issue.

Ref:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/pointing-devices-disappeared-from-within-device-manager/m-p/161142

## Solution

Follow these steps to perform a full Windows upgrade, it does take a few hours though it's the only thing I've found that solves the problem and gets your USB Mouse, Keyboard, Joystick and etc back working again:

**Take an OS image**

1. Using a PS2 keyboard (or a USB female to PS2 male converter) navigate to [Windows 10 download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10).
2. Download and save the "Create Windows 10 installation media" on your computer.

[image]

3. When the download is completed, as a Administrator logged into your PC run the Media Creation Tool (MediaCreationTool21H1.exe).
4. Accept the license agreement.
5. Choose Create installation media for another PC & click Next.

[image]

6. At the next screen choose Next. *
7. At 'Choose which media to use' choose ISO file and click Next.

[image]

8. Select a location to save the 'Windows.iso' file and click Save (typically a 4.5GB file).

**In place reinstall/upgrade using the OS image**

1. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to the folder you saved the 'Windows.iso' file.
2. Right-click on the ISO file and select Open With > Windows Explorer.
3. Double click the setup.exe application.
4. At 'Ready to Install' screen, make sure that the "Keep personal files and Apps" option is selected and click Install.

[image]

5. Wait for the inplace reinstall/upgrade process to complete.

After it finishes you can plugin your USB Keyboard and Mouse and they will work!